# How to invoke RESTful WCF service method with multiple parameters?

Tags: .net, wcf, json, rest, service

I have a RESTful WCF service with a method declared like this:

```
[OperationContract(Name = "IncrementAge")]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/", Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
Person IncrementAge(Person p);
```

Here's the implementation:

```
public Person IncrementAge(Person p)
{
            p.age++;

            return p;
}
```

So it takes the Person complex type, increments the age property by one, and spits it back, using JSON serialization. I can test the thing by sending a POST message to the service like this:

```
POST http://localhost:3602/RestService.svc/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3602
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 51

{"age":25,"firstName":"Hejhaj","surName":"Csuhaj"}
```

This works. What if I'd like to have a method like this?

```
Person IncrementAge(Person p, int amount);
```

So it'd have multiple parameters. How should I construct the POST message for this to work? Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a query string parameter,

```
POST /RestService.svc/Incrementor?amount=23
{...}
```

I think the WCF signature would be:

```
[OperationContract(Name = "IncrementAge")]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/?amount={amount}", Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
Person IncrementAge(int amount, Person p);
```

Comment: Using a query parameter to pass an argument that's *acted on* in a POST request seems a little strange to me. I'd reserve query parameters for *selecting* resources (to get or update), rather than for actually *modifying* the resources.

Comment: The problem is that IncrementAge returns a Person, so it is bordering a GET (i.e. Requests a specific representation of a resource). Granted though, that the method is more of an RPC call...

Answer (score 8):

You should make the message body style *wrapped* so that you can accept multiple arguments in the POST request body.

Your method signature will be:

```
[OperationContract(Name = "IncrementAge")]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/", Method = "POST",
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
Person IncrementAge(Person p, int amount);
```

And the body of the request will look like:

```
{"p": {"age":25,"firstName":"Hejhaj","surName":"Csuhaj"}, "amount": 1}
```

The outer JSON object is the anonymous wrapper.